# Выборка ордера по статусу продукта

Tags: mysql

Есть две таблицы

```
1) Orders
id - int
name - string

2) orders_products
id - int
order_id - int
product_id - int
status - id
```

Статус ордера = минимальному статусу у продукта находящегося в том ордере.
Пример:

```
    orders
    id = 1
    name = заказ№1

    id = 2
    name = заказ№2

    orders_products
    id = 1
    order_id = 1
    status = 1

    id = 2
    order_id = 1
    status = 2

    id = 3
    order_id = 2
    status = 2

    id = 4
    order_id = 2
    status = 5
```

Как получить список ордеров у которых статус равен 1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подзапросом

```
SELECT * FROM orders o WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT
    1
  FROM
    order_products op
  WHERE
    op.order_id = o.id
  HAVING
    MIN(op.status) = 1
)
```

Возможно такой запрос будет работать быстрее

```
SELECT
  o.*
FROM (
  SELECT
    order_id
  FROM
    order_products
  HAVING
    MIN(status) = 1
) op
LEFT JOIN orders o ON (
  op.order_id = o.id
)
```